# Augmented Reality with Python for smartphone

Tags: python, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

Are there tools available to build AR apps/games for Android/iOS with Python as a primary programming language?

For smartphones according to my research most used combination is Unity/Vuforia ( C#), but I would really like to use Python?

Comment: This is sadly an off topic question. [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any popular iOS/Android Python development frameworks at all (even just for apps).

However, there have been many Javascript-based iOS/Android app development frameworks (Xamarin, PhoneGap, React Native).

That being said, if you're interesting in building for AR/VR, my company has a React Native-based AR/VR platform called Viro React which will let you build cross-platform AR/VR experiences with React:

https://viromedia.com/viroreact

It exposes a scene-graph API for users in React Native so you can focus on creating your experience while we'll focus on all the intricacies of 3D rendering.

If you'd like something more imperative, you can check out ViroCore:

https://viromedia.com/virocore

Which is our Android/Java equivalent of Apple's SceneKit API.

Feel free to try it out, the platform is free to use and you can publish apps with it.

Comment: Oh thats really awesome , will definetly check it out . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but you could play around with Kivy (and integrate the OpenCV webcam), but it would require you to make most of the game from scratch.